# Returning an ordered set from a temp table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

In a stored procedure, I'm trying to return a dataset from a temp table in a certain order, but when I use the `Order By` clause on the `select * from #tempTable`, I get an error "Invalid column name" on whatever column I order by.

The code works in query analyzer window, but won't work inside a stored procedure, but the stored procedure will save and not throw errors.

Why is this and how do I get around it?

Here's the code:

```
SELECT
    c.CaseID,
    Person.PersonID,
    Person.LastName, Person.FirstName, Person.MiddleName
INTO 
    #People
FROM
    [Case] c 
INNER JOIN
    Person ON c.PersonID = Person.PersonID
WHERE
    c.CaseID = @caseID
ORDER BY
    c.CaseID 

SELECT * 
FROM #People 
ORDER BY CaseID
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, not that I thought I could. Create a stored procedure querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` into a temporary table, and end with a select from that temporary table with an order by clause. If you still experience a problem with it, add that stored procedure in its entirety in your question.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce it with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. would indexes on the source table cause issues?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you make a full repro case that does not use information schema? I mean, create script for the table and stored procedure, some inserts into the table, which shows the problem?

Comment: i'm headed out for the weekend, but i'll give it a shot on monday. Thanks!

Comment: :) wow early weekend! It's only wednesday!

Comment: lol, It was thanksgiving week in the US.
Anyway, I got back on Monday and the thing is working! Thanks for the help anyway.
Someone had suggested that I might need to list the columns on the final select to use the order by clause.

Comment: Ah yes, US thanksgiving, it's weird that that should show up in the news here in BE. So the holiday helped :). Case closed!

Comment: Use a variable table instead of a temp table, and why do you need the temp table anyway?

Answer (score -1):

-- You Have Mention the Column Names in the select statement --

```
CREATE TABLE #People (CaseID int identity(1,1) not null,
    PersonID int,LastName varchar(50),FirstName varchar(50),MiddleName varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #People
       VALUES(1,'P','RAJA','')
INSERT INTO #People
       VALUES(2,'S','Kannan','')
INSERT INTO #People
       VALUES(3,'A','Ravi','Kumar')
INSERT INTO #People
       VALUES(4,'D','Murugan','')
INSERT INTO #People
       VALUES(5,'G','Abhi','')
INSERT INTO #People
       VALUES(6,'R','Nayak','')

SELECT CaseID,PersonID,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName
FROM #People 
ORDER BY CaseID


DROP TABLE #People
```